# How to get the IP addresses of clients around me

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I'm developing a JAVA software and I want to ask the other clients for a database. This is a kinda shared DB which contains datas I wanna merge. Now my quiestion is: how can I detect the IPs of the other machines(on local network) using the same client software?

Comment: It would make more sense for the clients to discover the server's address. That way you only have to publish one IP address:port.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this before by having each client have a thread listening on a particular UDP port and then the querying client can send a broadcast on the LAN to that same port.